# Beautiful Soup to Find and Regex Replace text 'not within <a></a> '

Tags: python, html, find, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautiful Soup to parse a html to find all text that is

1.Not contained inside any anchor elements

I came up with this code which finds all links within href but not the other way around.

How can I modify this code to get only plain text using Beautiful Soup, so that I can do some find and replace and modify the soup?

```
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True):
    print a['href']
```

**EDIT:**

**Example:**

```
<html><body>
 <div> <a href="www.test1.com/identify">test1</a> </div>
 <div><br></div>
 <div><a href="www.test2.com/identify">test2</a></div>
 <div><br></div><div><br></div>
 <div>
   This should be identified 

   Identify me 1 

   Identify me 2 
   <p id="firstpara" align="center"> This paragraph should be<b> identified </b>.</p>
 </div>
</body></html>
```

**Output:**

```
This should be identified 
Identify me 1 
Identify me 2
This paragraph should be identified.
```

I am doing this operation to find text not within `<a></a>` : then find "Identify" and do replace operation with "Replaced"

So the final output will be like this:

```
<html><body>
 <div> <a href="www.test1.com/identify">test1</a> </div>
 <div><br></div>
 <div><a href="www.test2.com/identify">test2</a></div>
 <div><br></div><div><br></div>
 <div>
   This should be identified 

   Repalced me 1 

   Replaced me 2 
   <p id="firstpara" align="center"> This paragraph should be<b> identified </b>.</p>
 </div>
</body></html>
```

Thanks for your time !

Comment: html doesn't have `href` tags, anchor elements (`a`) do have `href` attributes. Your question is not clear, can you provide before and after examples of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I think he wants to get what could be links ("http://..." etc.) from plain text when they are not inside links.  Probable aim being a content filter which will linkify text links. Or then again, rereading point two, maybe he means to find text that *doesn't* contain text links? Definitely need more info.

Comment: @Chris Morgan I have added an example which meets my requirements...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you want to get the text that is inside an a element that contains an href attribute. If you want to get the text of the element, you can use the `.text` attribute.

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup()
>>> soup.feed('<a href="http://something.com">this is some text</a>')
>>> soup.findAll('a', href=True)[0]['href']
u'http://something.com'
>>> soup.findAll('a', href=True)[0].text
u'this is some text'
```

Edit

This finds all the text elements, with identified in them:

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup()
>>> soup.feed(yourhtml)
>>> [txt for txt in soup.findAll(text=True) if 'identified' in txt.lower()]
[u'\n   This should be identified \n\n   Identify me 1 \n\n   Identify me 2 \n   ', u' identified ']
```

The returned objects are of type `BeautifulSoup.NavigableString`. If you want to check if the parent is an `a` element you can do `txt.parent.name == 'a'`.

Another edit:

Here's another example with a regex and a replacement.

```
import BeautifulSoup
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup()
html = '''
<html><body>
 <div> <a href="www.test1.com/identify">test1</a> </div>
 <div><br></div>
 <div><a href="www.test2.com/identify">test2</a></div>
 <div><br></div><div><br></div>
 <div>
   This should be identified 

   Identify me 1 

   Identify me 2 
   <p id="firstpara" align="center"> This paragraph should be<b> identified </b>.</p>
 </div>
</body></html>
'''
soup.feed(html)
for txt in soup.findAll(text=True):
    if re.search('identi',txt,re.I) and txt.parent.name != 'a':
        newtext = re.sub(r'identi(\w+)', r'replace\1', txt.lower())
        txt.replaceWith(newtext)
print(soup)


<html><body>
<div> <a href="www.test1.com/identify">test1</a> </div>
<div><br /></div>
<div><a href="www.test2.com/identify">test2</a></div>
<div><br /></div><div><br /></div>
<div>
   this should be replacefied 

   replacefy me 1 

   replacefy me 2 
   <p id="firstpara" align="center"> This paragraph should be<b> replacefied </b>.</p>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I think he wants to get what could be links ("http://..." etc.) from plain text when they are not inside links instead.

Comment: @DiggyF I want to do what you did exactly the other way. I have added an example now to make it clear

Comment: @DiggyF How can I do replace operation within the present html itself, if the word is found? Also this code finds the word 'identified' even if it is within the <a></a> tags..Instead of 'identified' can I use a regex to match the needed pattern?.Thanks..